# bind window location

Tags: wpf, window, location

We try to bind the window location but the binding only works once when the window is loaded
(we do see the binding code entered).
Does anyone know why?

in view:

```
<Window Top="{Binding TopSize}">
   ...
</Window>
```

in view model:

```
public int TopSize
{
   get{return m_topSize;}
   set{m_topSize=value;}
}

private onTimer()
{
   m_topSize+=5;
   NotifyPropertychanged("TopSize");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/82ec9358-1f20-452f-8f7a-e067c999f262
This doesn't seem to work. If a value is set for Window.Top by the Framework your binding is gone.

What you could do is implement a Mediator/Event which notifies the Window with the correct value. Then set it manually in the window.

e.g.

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // create ViewModel and register for PropertyChanged
  var viewModel = new ViewModel();
  viewModel.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(viewModel_PropertyChanged);
  this.DataContext = viewModel;
}

void viewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // if topsize was changed set view accordingly
  if (e.PropertyName == "TopSize")
  {
    this.Top = ((ViewModel) this.DataContext).TopSize;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- Your timer runs more than once and doesn't self terminate.
- Your class is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

Interesting code construct. Try changing it to:

```
public int TopSize
{
  get{return m_topSize;}
  set
  {
    if (m_topSize!=value)
      m_topSize = value;
    NotifyPropertychanged("TopSize");  
  }
}
private onTimer()
{
  TopSize += 5;
}
```